# The exact meaning of n_jitted_steps=5

Tags: jax, flax

I have tried to run [the code](https://github.com/yang-song/score_sde). Here, there is a command called `n_jitted_steps=5`, which according to the authors, can accumulate several steps. Since the code is rather complicated, it might be difficult to understand. However, I have tried the following command [here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rwbfd/ce6b2f65d7dd8fc3335b962b2469eb5c/geek_bang_chapter_13_part2.ipynb) in Colab, where the relevant cell is

```
@jax.jit(n_jitted_steps=5)
def train_step(state, batch):
  """Train for a single step."""
  def loss_fn(params):
    logits = state.apply_fn({'params': params}, batch['image'])
    loss = optax.softmax_cross_entropy_with_integer_labels(
        logits=logits, labels=batch['label']).mean()
    return loss
  grad_fn = jax.grad(loss_fn)
  grads = grad_fn(state.params)
  state = state.apply_gradients(grads=grads)
  return state
```

Obviously, this creates an error. However, I wonder

1. Is the function of `n_jitted_steps=5` to send run five steps in one go, probably similar to loop unrolling?
2. If that is the case, what is the correct way to use it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the repository README the authors [say the following](https://github.com/yang-song/score_sde#tips):

> When using the JAX codebase, you can jit multiple training steps together to improve training speed at the cost of more memory usage. This can be set via `config.training.n_jitted_steps`

Note that `n_jitted_steps` is a parameter defined by the `score_sde` repository. In the notebook you link to, it seems like you're using `flax`, and not using any code from `score_sde`. Given that, I don't think your question is meaningful, because there is no equivalent of the `n_jitted_steps` parameter in `flax`.

Comment: Then may I ask how it is possible to do multiple loop unrolling? Thank you very much.